# How do you deploy a Streamlit app on App Engine (GCP)?

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment, google-cloud-platform, streamlit

I am aiming to deploy a simple web-app written with Sreamlit, e.g.

`app.py`

```
import streamlit as st
st.title('Hello World!')
```

I can run this on my local machine by running `streamlit run app.py` in my command line.

However, I'm not sure how to modify the app.yaml file in GCP's App Engine to deploy this.

Any advice?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use App Engine flexible environment for that as you can specify a [custom runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build#docker). The steps to follow will be:

1. Create the Dockerfile:

   ```
   FROM python:3.7
   EXPOSE 8080
   WORKDIR /app
   COPY requirements.txt ./requirements.txt
   RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
   COPY . .
   CMD streamlit run app.py --server.port 8080
   ```

   I have updated the Dockerfile as App Engine flex requires that the server listens on port 8080.
2. Create the requirements.txt file with the needed dependencies:

   ```
   streamlit
   ```
3. Create the app.yaml file:

   ```
   runtime: custom
   env: flex
   ```

   Both the app.yaml and the Dockerfile must be in the same folder. The above app.yaml settings are very basic, more information can be found in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/app-yaml).

Then to deploy you need to use the following gcloud command:`gcloud app deploy`

Comment: Hi there. Quick follow-up; would you do the same with Cloud Run? And is Cloud Run a better version of App Engine in most use cases?

Comment: With the Dockerfile you can deploy to Cloud Run as well, you can see all the needed steps [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy). Regarding Cloud Run vs App Engine and which is better, both products are Serverless and have their unique features. Cloud Run is based on Knative which is open-source and offers a pay-per-use billing model. It also supports Serverless VPC connectors so you can have the same connectivity to Storage products as when using App Engine Flex.

Comment: Also compared to GAE flex, Cloud Run will scale to 0 if there's no load, so that needs to be taken into consideration because you will have warmup requests if all of the serving instances have been shut down after being idle for a certain period of time.

Comment: Great answer, Thanks! I have another small inquiry: is there any option to use "standard" env? since using the flex env is much more cumbersome

Comment: @Shgidi I think you should be able to use it now, as before the limiting factor was the amount of libraries that you could install. With python 3+ you can install whatever library you need, as the docs [state](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#dependencies). Then you could include gunicorn among the dependencies needed and run it on [port 8080](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#dependencies]) I have not tried it myself but I think it sould work.

Comment: does not work for me on GAE flex, I'm getting an error from `gcloud app deploy`:
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [4] An internal error occurred while processing task /app-engine-flex/flex_await_healthy/flex_await_healthy>2022-11-29T07:55:05.850Z21335.wa.2: Your deployment has failed to become healthy in the allotted time and therefore was rolled back. If you believe this was an error, try adjusting the 'app_start_timeout_sec' setting in the 'readiness_check' section.